# Isn't Cast<T> implementation against Linq's immutable style?

Tags: c#, linq, immutability

This is how `Cast<T>` is implemented in the framework:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> enumerable = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        return enumerable; //the culprit
    }
    return Enumerable.CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

The problem I see is that `Cast<T>` returns the actual enumerable itself if some criterion is met. For instance this shouldn't happen:

```
var x = new List<string> { "1" };
var y = x.Cast<string>();

x.Add("2"); //reflects in y "immediately", since they are the same reference.
```

Or may be a more practical example:

```
object[] x = new[] { "1" };
var y = x.Cast<string>();

x[0] = "2"; //reflects in y "immediately", since they are the same reference.
```

[The documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) even says: *This method is implemented by using deferred execution.*, but not really in every case (as shown above). Similarly I can think of `AsEnumerable` as another culprit which returns itself.

**A situation where it can trip:**

```
var x = new List<string> { "1" }; //data source
var y = x.Cast<string>(); //query


((List<string>)y).Add("2"); //did something with the query

// Whoa, got the data source itself changed by tinkering the query
```

Questions:

1. Don't the two methods `AsEnumerable` and `Cast` violate the functional nature of Linq extension methods? May be I'm reading some guideline wrongly?
2. Are there more similar extension methods in `System.Linq` namespace which returns itself?

---

Ok guys, I supposed every linq method would produce a new sequence upon enumeration, which is the not the case here. May be I need not think like that.

But it seems there was a confusion regarding deferred execution. I expected a change to data source will be reflected in the `IEnumerable<T>` represented by the linq query only upon execution (I mean enumeration) of the query. For example, consider the below example:

```
var x = new List<int> { 1 };
var y = x.Cast<SomeEnum>();

x.Add(2); //at this stage the change to x is not reflected in y yet
```

In the above example, if I add a new element to `x`, `y` still points to a query, and the change to `x` is not reflected in `y`. I considered that as deferred execution, in the sense, one has to enumerate it to see the changes. Where as in the previous examples, the change was immediately reflected in `y`. So I thought it wasn't really deferred execution. Going by the answers here, my thinking was wrong.

Comment: Can you link me to where the documentation states LINQ sets out to make each method immutable?

Comment: I fail to see how `Cast<T>` changes anything resulting in violation of immutability

Comment: This isn't violation of deferred execution. *Every* LINQ method that returns an `IEnumerable` would include the added item.

Comment: Deferred execution *already means* that if the source changes, you can expect the result of iterating the query to change. This doesn't break deferred execution. And to have the immutability that you seem to think it says it has, you couldn't do deferred execution.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Maybe there is a misconception at the source of the question, but we should welcome anyone willing to learn..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Sorry I do not have, but my idea was that linq extension methods produced a new sequence every time an expression was applied. But if its not at all, then its worth making that an answer.

Comment: @Moho well I supposed if I apply `Cast` on `xx` (or any other linq method for that matter) it produces a new sequence `yy` which is not the case here. So in this case changes on `xx` is reflected in `yy` too.

Comment: I get an `InvalidCastException` when trying to execute the code casting `int` to `char`. It's not a valid example.

Comment: @Enigmativity oops, sorry for uncompiled examples. I will edit it. But you get the idea anyway.

Comment: Actually I don't get the idea yet. I want to see code where somethine added to the source list **doesn't** show up on the casted enumerable.

Comment: @Enigmativity *doesn't show up on the casted enumerable*.. you mean upon enumeration of cast enumerable?

Comment: I just ran the example with `.Cast<SomeEnum>()` and the added value does show up in the `y` enumerable. There doesn't seem to be much of an issue here?

Comment: @Enigmativity `and the added value does show up in the y enumerable`... I keep asking, when you enumerated `y`, or the moment u added to `x`? Only when you enumerate you get it it in `y`, unlike in previous example in the question. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: But there is no distinction. The behaviour is the same in all the examples.

Comment: The end result of the behaviour is same (at least for the client it shouldnt matter), but the way they behave is subtly different. Well I at first thought it should be a problem, alas, upon more thinking, I realized I need not worry about it.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The examples you give, that manipulating the source array affects the output of the enumeration, is actually due to the deferred execution. So they don't suggest deferred execution is not happening.

It makes no difference if you get a reference to the original list, or to the `CastIterator`. The latter will lazily evaluate the source, so changes are reflected in both cases.

If C# were a pure functional language, Linq could be lazy (deferred) and would return an iteration that would not change over time.

But C# is not a pure functional language.

The Linq team had to choose, and implemented the lazy part. Immutability would be more costly to enforce within Linq. But if you want immutability, you can get it: just stop changing the source, or make snapshots using `ToArray()` when appropriate.

Comment: @nawfal: yes, but I don't see the point you're making. It is sometimes possible to edit LINQ-to-objects data sources afterward, but that is mostly interesting to test deferred execution without a debugger. Don't write code that does it, or depends on it.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't. But there are cases where this can happen. For example, if I'm to return a query to client, like `object[] x = new[] { "1" }; return x.Cast<string>();`, and if the client happens to cast it back to array type and edit it, my data source is affected. It feels like a poor implementation to me.

Comment: I see. If you can't trust your clients you'd need to add an extra level of indirection, in your case a wrapper around `IEnumerable<T>`. This is not part of LINQ, and probably on purpose, as it would add runtime cost by itself, and also prevent certain optimizations. For instance, if you `Count()` an `IEnumerable<T>`, LINQ checks if the `IEnumerable<T>` is a `ICollection<T>`, and if so returns the collection's count. Otherwise it enumates all elements to count them which is considerably more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is exactly deferred execution. You express a query on a data source in LINQ, in this case an in-memory list, and once you iterate over the LINQ returned IEnumerable, the query is actually executed on the current state of the data source.

If the changes were not reflected in the IEnumerable returned by LINQ, this would be eager execution instead.

Comment: Oliver, I hope the question is clear now. Indeed I had worded it poorly. The problem is not that the change to data source is getting reflected on enumeration of the query. It was that, one, the query itself represented data source, and two, consequently, the change was instant (without requirement of enumeration of query). Well I think now, its not a problem really.

Comment: @nawfal What do you mean by "immediately"?  The sequence doesn't represent any items until enumerated.  *It represents a query, not the results of the query*.  How would this implementation ever function any differently (outside of performance) than if it didn't do what it did?  Show how an implementation without this would function differently.

Comment: @Servy The sequence in the first example did represent items even before enumerated, so I was getting suspicious. Well, you are right, the end behaviour is all the same, which is what matters, but the ends are achieved in subtly different ways, which prompted me to ask this question. Just to explain the subtle difference, the Cast in first example returns the source as such, while that in the last example returns a cast iterator.